# Script returns strange error. Can someone explain?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to write data to an external Sheet, but I am receiving a strange error.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
var payData = trackingSheet.getRange('C250:E250').getValues();

     var paycheckHistorySheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('10kFR2EPO4RYuiJDun0WVO----------y8bEG3R3_Xyc'); // This is the 'Paycheck History Sheet'

     paycheckHistorySheet.appendRow([payData]);
```

As you can tell by the code above, I'm trying to import the data in the "Tracking Sheet" to the last line in the "Paycheck History" sheet. However, when I run the script, in the "Paycheck History Sheet", I'm receiving the error "[Ljava.lang.Object;@6ba282".

Why is this happening, how can I prevent it, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Think about what `appendRow()` [accepts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)) - an `Object[]`, whereas `getValues()` returns an `Array` of `Array`s of `Object`. You need to extract value at index `[0]` since `C250:E250` represents a row, and pass it to `appendRow` without wrapping in another `Array`

Comment: Oleg, thank you. You're right.

Comment: No problem - btw, the `Ljava.lang` error is due to older Rhino runtime for JavaScript (on which Google Apps Script is based) is written in Java. It is worth switching to the newer [V8](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration) runtime

Comment: The script was just created about 6 hours ago. Won't all new/recent scripts default to the new V8?

Comment: Actually, it should (and thanks for pointing out). If `runtimeVersion` in manifest is `V8`, then it should. Hovewer, V8 is written in C++, which means something under the hood is still Java-based, which sounds a bit odd

Comment: Sounds like I'm headed over to getLastRow...

Comment: For the `getRange()` call?

Comment: Sorry about the delay - yes, for use with getRange.

Comment: Yeah, if you found the range to be changing fro `C250:E250` in the future, `getLastRow()` is method of choice (unless I misunderstood your comment - sorry in advance)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

Passing an argument of different type that a method expects.

**Explanation**

`appendRow()` accepts an `Object[]`, whereas `getValues()` returns an `Array` of `Array` of `Object`. To pass values to `appendRow()`, one has to extract value at index `[0]` (more general - at any index if `Range` is more than a row or target row is not the first one) without wrapping it in another `Array`.

**Samples**

This is what `getValues()` returns:

```
const grid = [
   [ r0c0, ... , r0cN ],
   ...
   [ rMc0, ... , rMcN ]
];
```

**References**

1. `appendRow()` method [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))
2. `getValues()` method [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
3. On [multidimensional](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multidimensional-array-in-javascript/) arrays in JavaScript